# icon error in createNotification in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

In my Chrome Extension, I am using webkitNotifications.createNotification to alert users. It's a great tool!! In the sample code given, the first parameter is optional and specifies an an icon and the Google instructions claim that it can be a local reference. When I use a local file, I get a broken image link. This even occurs when I use the sample for Notification Demo located here - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#f799e26ceef2367cf836f24bcb47df4398b0df58

Does anyone else have this issue?

The icon is listed in my manifest file.

I can get around this by using a complete web reference, but I like to use this tool for error notifications and sometimes the error is caused by an interruption of internet access.

I am using chrome version 18.0.1025.151 m.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with their sample is they have included `"manifest_version": 2` in their manifest but not added a `"web_accessible_resources"` listing what resources should be available to pages.
You can read more about manifest_version 2 and what changes it introduces here....
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html
...and about web_accessible_resources here....
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources

To fix the problem in the sample, you can either remove the manifest version 2 bit (even the docs say this wont be required for a while yet).  Or you can add the following to the manifest....

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "48.png"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

"Web Accessible" means the resources is being accessed from your server so you must make sure to include the path to the resources in your javascript and in the manifest,json.